# Bootstrap data-time into database

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I need help to understand this:

How to send "TIME&DATE" which I choose in advance to my database using bootstrap?

first: whats the column type in the database? is it "DATE"?
second: in which way do I send this? (with post method in a  form?)

Comment: Apples and asterisks, with respect.  Bootstrap handles web page layout, and does it well. But it doesn't handle database interactions. You'll need some sort of backend program to communicate between your web page and your database. You'll need some sort of front-end program to send requests to your back end.

Comment: Yes I am using php to do so. Maybe my question was a bit unclear. I ment how to handle the boostrape date , so that i can send it and store it an database with php.